# VSCode Keyboard command ids

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When creating or editing the keybindings.json file v1.2.1 of Visual Studio Code requires not only the key to bind but also the 'CommandID' and 'When' condition.

I am looking for a complete list of 'CommandIDs' available to use and have been unable to find one. Where is that complete list of commands ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Preferences > Open Keyboard Shortcuts.

Click to edit keybindings.json for advanced customization. At the bottom of keybindings.json is a list of available commands:

`// Here are other available commands:`

This is mentioned (but hard to find) on the page shared by seairth.

Comment: What if that file is modified and the default list is not there? How can we discover commands?

Comment: For me (on Mac) only this worked to see the json file: [Cmd + Shift + P] > "Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"

Answer (score 3):

Open command palette with `Ctrl/Cmd + p` and type in **Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts(JSON)**

then `Enter` or click on it

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings) for the default list.

Comment: I could have been more clear on the question. That page I did find however what is not clear to me if if that page has the totality of commandID.  This page shows the key bindings already configured.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the complete list for just VSCode.  However, extensions can contribute commands as well, so a truly complete listing is going to also depend on which extensions are installed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't trivial, but does answer the question.

You can retrieve all commands from within a VS Code Extension.  So if you [create your own](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) like this:

```sh
npm install -g yo generator-code
yo code
```

Then you can use the [`commands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands) object like this:

```
let commands = await vscode.commands.getCommands()
```

Which does the following according to the docs:

> Retrieve the list of all available commands. Commands starting with an underscore are treated as internal commands.

**See Also**: [List of all available commands in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58367207/1366033)