# List of all available commands in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where can I find the list of **all commands** available in VSCode and their **description**?

I'm only aware of these sources:

#### In the official docs:

- [This list](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) which only seems to include **a subset** of Visual Studio Code commands that you might use with `vscode.commands.executeCommand API` (*why is this only a subset of the full list?*)
- [This other list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) in the keybindings doc, which also only seems to include a **subset** of all commands available (*I suppose those tied to a default keybinding?*)

#### In the editor itself:

I can see a list of commands when I open the "default keybindings". Many actions are commented out with `//`, but interestingly I don't think this includes all the commands either (e.g. `maximizeOtherEditor` isn't listed)

---

Does VSCode have an official list of commands (`commandID`'s) either in its documentation or in its code base?  If not:

- What's the closest to it?
- What's a good way to navigate the code base to try to find all commands and what they do?

Comment: Are you talking about command pallette commands?

Comment: Thanks @ShawnMelton I'm talking about `command IDs` (e.g. `workbench.action.joinAllGroups`). Are they different? What's their relationship?

Comment: If the reason for asking this question is that you want to manage your key-bindings, you _might_ be helped by [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184034#61729493](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184034#61729493).

Comment: This is an issue asking for that: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/683. Guys who are led here by google, if you need it, please express your opinions there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I *believe* that content of "Preferences: Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" (command ID `workbench.action.openDefaultKeybindingsFile`) really shows comprehensive list of **all native and extensions-contributed commands** VSC knows about at moment when invoked.

This file shows `key`s from VSC's defaults and extension manifests.
Commands with no suggested defaults are those commented out at the end of file.

Their **descriptions** (as seen in the Command Palette, Keyboard Shortcuts settings, extension Contributions tab and elsewhere) are supposedly in localization properties and I believe there is currently **no way to see them along their respective command IDs** in single convenient "localized" list. So for now the only way to read the description of command found in aforementioned JSON is pasting its ID into Keyboard Shortcuts search field.  (Would be delighted to be proven wrong.)

Comment: There is also a command `vscode.commands.getCommands()` which returns all available commands programaticaly.  It does so without giving you details/a description/... though...

Comment: Even in `workbench.action.openDefaultKeybindingsFile` there are some commands missing. e.g.: `workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd` defined here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39#_open-new-terminals-with-custom-working-directories

Comment: You are right indeed. What is strange is that this command is completely omitted from Keyboard Shortcuts GUI (perhaps because this "args" command kind have no GUI in general?), but *is* present in intellisense/validation of the keybindings.json

Comment: It's also missing "Feature Contributions" from extensions, I came across this post hoping to find a solution to getting a full list of all extension's available commands as well as all internal commands.