# Pass argument to VSCode command in tasks.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arguments, command, parameter-passing, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to automate some stuff for a project, for example search for dates in the files in the project directory, and then copy any found dates into a separate file.

Seems like tasks *maybe* could do this? But I'm having trouble, unsurprisingly.

I managed to find a way to run [vscode commands from tasks.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470525/how-can-i-run-a-vscode-command-as-a-task), like this for example

```
"label" : "Test Command",    
"command" : "${command:editor.action.copyLinesDownAction}",
```

Which literally copies and pastes the line the cursor is on.

This is a good start, but I can't figure out how to pass arguments to commands like this. For example, I'd like to create a command that simply types out the current working directory, so I try

```
"label" : "Print CWD",
"command": "${command:type}", //Not even sure this is the right command, tbh
```

Which does nothing. It doesn't throw an error, either, which is nice, but it has no effect. I cannot figure out where to put the "type this string" argument, and I can't find documentation on these commands either.

Here's a [Stack Exchange thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367207/list-of-all-available-commands-in-vscode) with links to all/many vscode commands, most of which I can't find documentation on.

Anyway, hope this question is relatively clear. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks.

Oh also, I'm happy to hear alternatives. Though, I'm trying to do this installing as little stuff as possible.